# Django performance with render_to_response

Tags: python, django, performance, templates

I have Django app, which have following statements:

```
    response = render_to_response('template.html', {'s':s, 'r':r}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The typical statement at template.html is:

```
    <tbody>{%for m in r.m_set.all %}<tr>
    <td>{{m.id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{m.MaterialLot.id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.MaterialSublot.id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Description|truncatechars:20}}</td>
    <td>{{m.StorageLocation.id}} - {{m.StorageLocation.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Quantity|floatformat:"-3"}}</td>
    <td>{{m.QuantityUnitOfMeasure.id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Status.id}}</td></tr>  {%endfor%}</tbody>
```

There are about 10 thousands records. the page response time take about 3 minutes(ThinkServer, Linux, Apache, mod_wsgi, Python3.4, Django 1.9.4, MySQL), is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your models. It looks to me like you're doing queries in each iteration of that loop, which would explain why it's so slow.

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `{{ m.XXX.id }}` leads to separate SQL-query for the `XXX` instance.  To avoid this you should use the `select_related()` method of the queryset.

Add the following method to the class of the `r` variable:

```
def get_all_m(self):
    return self.m_set.all().select_related()
```

and then use it in the template:

```
{% for m in r.get_all_m %}
```

Comment: `select_related()` for every related model is unnecessary--it's only needed for the `StorageLocation` field. The value of the foreign key can be used for the others.

Answer (score 0):

To only access the id of the related models, add the `_id` suffix to the field name. This data is already available because that's the value of the foreign key, so you don't need extra queries or joins. However, you *are* accessing the `Name` property of the `StorageLocation` field, so you need a join to prevent doing a query in every iteration.

Your call for the data becomes:

```
r.m_set.select_related('StorageLocation').all()
```

Your template becomes:

```
<tbody>
{%for m in r.m_set.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{m.id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{m.MaterialLot_id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.MaterialSublot_id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Description|truncatechars:20}}</td>
    <td>{{m.StorageLocation.id}} - {{m.StorageLocation.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Quantity|floatformat:"-3"}}</td>
    <td>{{m.QuantityUnitOfMeasure_id}}</td>
    <td>{{m.Status_id}}</td>
  </tr>  
{%endfor%}
</tbody>
```

Just remember that if you need access to a field other than `id` on a related model, add the field name to the `select_related()` call.